# 3D plot out of a 2D arrays plotly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, plotly

I'm currently try to plot a set of 2D arrays into a 3D plot basically I would like to plot the array as an isosurface and stack them together. The closest example which I could find that kind of works is the following code

```
[import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

z1 = np.array(\[
    \[8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87\],
    \[8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92\],
    \[8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91\],
    \[8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92\],
    \[8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92\],
    \[8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92\],
    \[8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92\],
    \[8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94\],
    \[8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99\],
    \[8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11\],
    \[8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11\],
    \[9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27\],
    \[9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2\],
    \[8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19\],
    \[8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18\]
\])

z2 = z1 + 1
z3 = z1 - 1

fig = go.Figure(data=\[
    go.Surface(z=z1),
    go.Surface(z=z2, showscale=False, opacity=0.9),
    go.Surface(z=z3, showscale=False, opacity=0.9)

\])

fig.show()][1]
```

Which gives the following figure [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58sxw.png)  (the example is also here https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/):
In this plot the separation in the z-axis is given by adding + 1 and -1 to z1 ( z2 = z1 + 1
z3 = z1 - 1 ) but this has the issue of actually changing the values of the 2d arrays.

Is there a way to plot the 2d Arrays in the same way but without changing the values of the array itself? meaning, I guess, adding a separation value between them.
P.s also an answer in the standard matplotlib would be great!

Many thanks!